# How to display $\varnothing$ in tikz file

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to create a graphic file with tikz package. But I can not display empty set symbol in `$\varnothing$` (it can display `$\emptyset$`). I need help on this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ti*k*Z but only with the packages that you (do not) load. Just load `amssymb`: `\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw]{$\varnothing$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This had nothing to do with `tikz`. You only need to load `amssymb`. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw]{$\varnothing$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]